# Password-based client login over TCP/TLS

Tags: tls, authentication, passwords, session-management, tcp

A client connects to a server through an application (not a web browser) with a long-running TCP connection. TLS is used, so the communication is secure.

Is there a standard way to implement a password-based login mechanism in this scenario?

The simple option would be this: have the client submit a username and password just once after the connection is established, and then have the server hash the password and check against a stored value (again, just once). Since the TCP/TLS connection is stateful, I believe there is no need for session cookies/tokens. Is this simple option satisfactory?

Comment: Maybe pay attention to the hashing part, maybe you could use PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt or something newer. And of course, always use salt.

Comment: Agree, it's worth doing that part carefully. Does the simple option seem reasonable otherwise?

Comment: You aren't worried about session stealing? Not worried about malicious actors sending spoofed packets? You have not stated your requirements for "satisfactory".

Comment: @schroeder That's why I'm asking the question! I'm trying to figure out if there's something I haven't considered.

Comment: There is a lot that you have not considered. This is not the right place to ask how to design an authentication system from scratch. Use the many Web based secure systems as design examples.

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear enough. I'm aware that there is plenty of information about how to design authentication systems over HTTPS. But if the client just sets up a long-running TCP connection (as opposed to request/response) I can't see why exchanging session tokens (or similar) would be necessary. But if you don't have the machinery of session tokens, how do you log in? Is it as simple as: send the username/password?

Comment: "TLS is used" is not enough: is it authenticated on *both* sides with client certificates and does each side really validate the other side certificate? Have a look at: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf   After that, many other points: you can have a TLS session with NULL encryption, so care is needed with configuration, specially on server, list of algorithms, protocol version, etc.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Interesting link, thank you. In this case client certificates are not used, which is why I'm looking into the login mechanism. But yes, my question assumes that TLS is not mis-configured.

Comment: If no authentication at TLS level, then absolutely no passwords in clear (because the sender has no true guarantee it is really the good server). SASL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) is the generic framework to use for this problem. So do you use its PLAIN version.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The client can check the server's certificate... What I'm discussing is how to authenticate the client to the server with a username/password.

Comment: Check my previous comment, and I wanted to say "Do **NOT** use its PLAIN mechanism"